# Cron job missed JSON get request on wget

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, cron

I am making a crob job that is supposed to load a page that receives JSON code from eventSource

What happens is when i go to website www.example.com/JSON it will get code every 15 seconds in JSON and save to a database in MYSQL

In order to get the code without loading the site, I am making a cron job (which loads every minute, but the JSON code is sent every 15 seconds.)

Does the CRON job miss the AJAX call, or do I have to use a different call besides

```
*/1 * * * * wget http://example.com/JSON.php
```

The php code looks like

```
eventSource.addEventListener('20sec', function (e) {
                var parsedData = JSON.parse(e.data);
```

Comment: That is certainly javascript not PHP. CRON will definitely not execute javascript.

Answer (score 0):

OK personally .. I have done (sort of) what you are describing.  Here is how I accomplished it.

I called the php script via cron

`*/1 * * * * php /your/path/to/getJSON.php`

Inside the getJSON.php file .. Just:

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('http://example.com/json_suff.php');
if (empty(json_decode($jsondata, 1))) {
// write to error log
exit();
} else {
//do your SQL stuff
}
```

Comment: Ill try it, just wanted to get consultation on the php path being changed from wget.

Comment: My cron job on the bluehost server doesn't work. I need the page to be loaded and intercept the JSON code.